# Show a list of members whose status = 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to achieve two things.

1. When the user registers he is by default a member but status is 0, which means not approved by admin yet.  What would the SQL be to list all members with status 0?
2. If I had a list of status zero members, what would be best way to change from 0 to 1?  I'd like to use a dropdown box or radio button to control this, is the SQL to change it `ALTER`?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`lname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`usertype` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'm',
`status` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Comment: google for `select` and `where`. and `update` for change user status.

Comment: You need to learn basic sql. `select` is for fetching data, `update` is for changing records. `alter` is for modifying the structure of a table.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = 0` list will be displayed and to updates status of all user from 0 to 1 try `UPDATE user SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0`

Comment: What the heck is "too broad" about this question? Was it really that hard to post a helpful answer instead of a snide remark? I guess we could be a bit nicer towards a beginner.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. 
Yes I have checked the commands given and have the resutls shwoing in list which I'm happy with. I also foudn the 'UPDATE user SET status' too but how would I have it that I can select username seperatly and set it as 1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the code to update it from 0 to 1 as this

    `UPDATE USER
    SET approved='1'
    WHERE username='';`

How would it work that I can select the usernames individually and submit it so it will update..

Comment: @georg Even a beginner could read an 'SQL getting started' before asking two different SQL questions into one, one of them being whether 'alter' is used to update a record. Also, the question just mentiones a dropdown, so it's hardly clear whether it's just about the update statement, to me it sounds like asking for the complete client-server interaction. I think closing as 'too broad' is just here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all details on users with status = 0 you need to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = 0;
```

To update your table, you need to use an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE user SET status = 1 WHERE username = '$username';
  //   ^table to update                       ^this needs to be set before (and shouldn't be used like this - see the script for prepared statements
```

A very basic script to do what you want would be:

```
<?php
 $sql = new mysqli('localhost','DB_USER','DB_USER_PASS','DB_TO_CONNECT_TO'); // you need to edit this with your real credentials / connection details

 $sql -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
 if ($sql->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $sql->connect_error);
    exit();
 }

 if (isset($_POST['updateuser'])) {  // checks if you want to update someone
 $stmt = $sql->prepare("UPDATE user SET status = 1 WHERE username = ?"); //prepare a query to your DB
 $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['username']); //bind the value to your query
 $stmt->execute(); // run the query
 }

 $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE status = 0"; // show all users with status 0
 ?>
 <form name='statzerouser' method='post' action=''>
 <label for='username'>User with status 0</label>
 <select name='username' id='username'> 
 <?php
 if ($result = $sql->query($query)) {
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?>
 <option value='<?= $row['username']; ?>'><?= $row['username']; ?></option> <!-- get all users with status 0 in a select dropdown -->
 <?php
 }
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 <input type='submit' name='updateuser' value='submit'/>
 </form>
```

**NOTE:**

Instead of [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), you might want to learn [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) right from the start. Both is used for connections to your database. In both cases, if you find a tutorial that shows you an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE user SET status = 1 WHERE username = '$username';
```

**change the tutorial and find one which is using prepared statements!**